# Deploy Maven artifacts on Sonatype Nexus repository hosted on Linux

Tags: linux, deployment, maven, nexus

I am new to [Sonatype Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) and Maven and trying examples as given in [Maven by Example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html).
I have a problem deploying artifacts generated by Maven to Nexus running on Linux.
If my `pom.xml` has 'localhost:8081' as the repository, the deployment is a success. If I replace localhost with an IP address (10.193.4.5:8081) deployment fails with 'Access denied' error. Details below.

```
Error:
Downloading: h ttp://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple/parent/0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple:parent:0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to testing
(http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to: http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple/parent/0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException:
Could not transfer metadata org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple:parent:0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to testing (http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to:
http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple/parent/0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

My configuration details are as follows.

1. Nexus (nexus-oss-webapp-1.9.1.1) installed on linux_x64 (RHEL5) as "root" user and running as service
2. Maven
    Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 23:01:09+0530)
    Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3
    Java version: 1.6.0_16, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Java home: /usr/java1.6.0_16/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.18-8.el5", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
3. `settings.xml`

   snapshots
   deployment
   deployment
4. `pom.xml`

   testing
   Internal Releases

   http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>-->

   http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots

I guess this is related to a permission problem on Linux, and I am not able to debug.

1. What should be the ideal user for Nexus to run root or Nexus?
2. What should be the group and owner for a Sonatype-work folder?

Comment: I am not familiar with Nexus, but this looks more like a nexus setup problem than a file permission problem to me. Did you check your nexus security settings?

Comment: I'm confused... Are you running Nexus on your local box? Is your IP 10.193.4.5?

Comment: Yes, 10.193.4.5 is the ip of my linux system.

Comment: When you add a comment, if you want to get someone's attention, you need to @<user> them. e.g., you'd want to add @Ryan to get my attention. I just happened to notice you had replied to my question, or I wouldn't have known.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to networking and not to the Nexus setup. Try

```
nc -vz 10.193.4.5 8081
```

at the console to see if you can route packets to that address. To make it work with the IP, you'll probably need to add an /etc/hosts entry.

Comment: :"Connection to 10.193.4.5 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!".

Comment: I tried the nc command from the linux system and its succeeded.

Comment: Then maybe nexus really is the one denying access. What about `wget http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple/parent/0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, I am able to download the xml using wget. (PS: This xml was deployed to sonatype nexus using localhost. 'Access denied error' is when deploying using IP)

Comment: @Bala: You don't happen to be changing the repository's id when you change localhost to 10.193.4.5, do you?

Comment: NO, I am not changing anything else.  I am just replacing localhost to 10.193.4.5

Comment: @Bala: Oh, wait, wait... I just noticed that there's XML that isn't showing up in your question. If the id of the repository you're deploying to is "testing", then the server id in your settings.xml needs to also be "testing". Server id must match repository id.

Comment: :ID in pom.xml and settings.xml are same.  I created a testing repository to debug further on this issue.

Comment: pom.xml:
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>

      <id>testing</id>

      <name>Internal Releases</name>
      <url>http://10.193.4.5:8081/nexus/content/repositories/testing</url>

    </repository>

  </distributionManagement>

settings.xml
    <server>
      <id>testing</id>
    <username>deployment</username>
    <password>deployment</password>
  </server>

Comment: :Thanks for your time, suggestions & feedback.  I don't know how, but the problem is solved now.  I restarted my Linux system and deployment is working with IP.